# How to make a data library

Tags: c

This code is running correctly but I want to make a library contain all these data types to use it in any program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void){
typedef unsigned char uint8_t ;
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t ;
typedef unsigned long int uint32_t ;
typedef signed char sint8_t ;
typedef signed short int sint16_t ;
typedef signed long int sint32_t ;
typedef float float32_t ;
typedef double float64_t ;
printf("Size Of Unsigned Char = %d ",sizeof(uint8_t));   //1
printf("\n");
printf("Size Of Unsigned Short Integer = %d ",sizeof(uint16_t));   //2
printf("\n");
printf("Size Of signed Long Integer = %d ",sizeof(sint32_t));   //4
printf("\n");
printf("Size Of Unsigned Char = %d ",sizeof(float64_t));   //8
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `"Size Of Unsigned Char = %d ",sizeof(float64_t)`... Say what???

Comment: Do you mean a header file? The `stdint.h` system (standard) header has `typedef` statements very similar to yours for the `int32_t` and related types.

Comment: Unless you have an extremely good reason for doing otherwise, you should use the [standard fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) defined in `stdint.h`.

Comment: thank you guys iam new to c language so i dont know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would'nt make a library but rather a header file.

```
#ifndef _my_types_h_included_
#define _my_types_h_included_

typedef unsigned char uint8_t ;
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t ;
typedef unsigned long int uint32_t ;
typedef signed char sint8_t ;
typedef signed short int sint16_t ;
typedef signed long int sint32_t ;
typedef float float32_t ;
typedef double float64_t ;

#endif
```

Then you'd include that file in your c files like this:

```
#include "my_types.h"
...
uint8_t foo;
...
```

For more information google this:

- c header guards
- c header file

---

But anyway, you should rather use `#include <stdint.h>`, which defines types like `uint8_t` etc. in a standard manner.

Comment: ,yeah thats excatly what iam looking for..thanks